# Corona button with text and icon?

Tags: button, text, icons, coronasdk

Is it possible to have a Corona button with label text and a icon? Something like this:

```
 ,===============,
 [   Action  •   ]
 `===============`
```

The bullet representing the icon, and `Action` representing the label text.

Is this possible to build buttons like this using the Corona widget library?

Comment: Have a look at the [DMC Lib for Corona](https://github.com/dmccuskey/DMC-Corona-Library), there is a class dmc_buttons with some nice enhancement compared to the basic corona buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this for example, on a rectangle button I want a arrow image with "NEXT" text which will look like "NEXT->"

There are two ways that you could do this:

1. Create the button background image with the -> on it, and use that for the Next button.
2. If you don't want to do that so you can keep the same background image for multiple buttons (ones with and without the ->), then create the widget button and position it.  Put blank spaces in the text label for where you want the -> image to go, then calculate the position of the button and add a new image (not button) on top of it. Since I knew the buttons were never going to move and were always in the same position, it was fairly easy.

Comment: I wanted more control over the button so I ended up just overlaying the text and icon (as an image) on top of a blank button. I am accepting this answer as it is the closest to what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you'll need to code it yourself. I personally like to do my buttons with an image and add an event listener to it, something like this:

```
local function methodOnTap( event )
    print("Hey!! you tapped me!")
end

local buttonWithImage = display.newImage( "image.png")
buttonWithImage:addEventListener( "tap", methodOnTap )
```

this is a simple explanation on how to do a button with an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use also text in your button you can use a class and make the button with image and text! :)
And then you call the function and use this class ;)

as shown over, you can call the class, if your class name is buttonC then it's going to be buttonC:addEventListener("tap",methodOnTap)